# Does Android studio support window 7 32 bit? SDK folder is missing in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager, appium-desktop

While installing Android studio, SDK is unavailable on my "AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

I am trying on windows7 32 bit. could any one help me to sort out this issue??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhYg5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z08KD.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install the latest Android Studio(4.1.3) on the windows 7(32 bit) system.

To install the latest version of Android Studio you need Windows 7(64 bit) system.

Following are the minimum requirements to install Android Studio.

- Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (64-bit)
- 4 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
- 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution